# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working at all

Tags: apache

I have an error when try to put my chat on my webiste

> Failed to load
>   https://chat.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MBK-pzZ:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 503.

on my VH on apache I did:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
    SSLEngine on
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/public_html
    UseCanonicalName OFF
        <Directory /home/myuser/public_html>
    Options None
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but it's not help.
using apache 2.4

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was with my apache configuration the "httpd-default.conf"

I found this 2 lines:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

when i remove it, it's works

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also put these lines in .htacces file to fix this issue.

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```